# How Can I remove the metadatas of a .py file?

Tags: python

I feel me embarrassed for ask this question, but I've never had a problem like that, I can't remove the ***metadatas*** of a Python File.
First I've tried with the simple tool of Windows but I didn't get nothing, even when I click "Select All the Items", It doesn't show nothing!

[image]

Secondly I've tried with the *exiftool.exe*, but without a solution,
[image]

Comment: What data are you trying to get rid of? .py files are usually just text - they don't have inherent metadata, just data which Windows knows from having access to the file, such as the file size, creation and modification times, and the current location of the file. From the screenshot, it's showing the file name, the file type, the path to the file, the file size, creation and modification timestamps, that the archive attribute is set, and some info about the current computer, none of which is in the file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python files (`.py`) are just text files with a different extension that allows the operating system to easily recognise them. The 'metadata' seen in the Properties window is simply some information that is associated with *every* file, like the creation date.

The tool you are trying to use is for removing `EXIF` data from photo's. `EXIF` data is normally only included in image files, and your tool will not be able to remove it if it doesn't exist.

If you want to remove the information from the properties window before you send the file to others, there is no need to do so. When you send the file to other people normally (e.g. via e-mail) only the contents of the file (and sometimes the filename) is sent, no other metadata.